# How to update Eclipse status line?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am performing background operations initiated from Remote Systems view. How do I update the progress on status line?

In summary, how to write a message to the Eclipse SDK status line?

[image]

Comment: you dont... you just wait until is done!

Comment: Your image shows the progress area. That is updated by Jobs run by Eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The **message** displayed in the status bar **is the name of the** (long running) **[job](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/Job.html#Job-java.lang.String-)**, which is scheduled and run by Eclipse. The progress percentage is updated within the job via the IProgressMonitor.

See: [Eclipse Jobs and Background Processing - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html)